Pandas: Supporting a time past 24:00:00
I'm trying to manipulate a dataset that contains stop times of trains in stations. This data only contains the times and not the dates. In this dataset, there can be times that are past 24:00:00. For example, if a train leaves at 23:50 of Day1 and arrives at 00:18 of Day2, the arrival time would be marked as 24:18:00, which of course creates problems for the datetime conversion that I'm trying to perform.
In particular, this is the code I'm trying to execute:
Trains["arrival_time"] = pd.to_datetime(Trains["arrival_time"], format = '%H:%M:%S')

And this is the error I get:
ValueError: time data "24:18:00" doesn't match format "%H:%M:%S", at position 277. You might want to try:
    - passing `format` if your strings have a consistent format;
    - passing `format='ISO8601'` if your strings are all ISO8601 but not necessarily in exactly the same format;
    - passing `format='mixed'`, and the format will be inferred for each element individually. You might want to use `dayfirst` alongside this.


Use to_timedelta to convert your time, it handles well deltas above 24h.
If you want to combine it to an existing date:
df['datime'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['arrival_date'])
               +pd.to_timedelta(df['arrival_time'])
               )

Output:
  arrival_date arrival_time              datime
0   2024-07-14     24:18:00 2024-07-15 00:18:00

If you want to get the valid time, you could use a modulo 24h:
pd.to_timedelta(df['arrival_time']) % pd.Timedelta('24h')

0   0 days 00:18:00
Name: arrival_time, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

# or as string
(pd.to_timedelta(df['arrival_time'])
   .mod(pd.Timedelta('24h'))
   .add(pd.Timestamp(0)).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
)

0    00:18:00
Name: arrival_time, dtype: object


If the time is greater than 24:00:00, subtract 24 hours from it (and add one to the day, if you care about dates).

How do you subtract if you can't parse it?

@wjandrea Any number of ways.  Off the top of my head -- split the string on colons and check if the first part is equal to "24" and either the second or third parts are greater than "00".
